# Designing a REST service with akka-http and akka-stream

Tags: scala, rest, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm new to akka http & streams and would like to figure out what the most idiomatic implementation is for a REST api. Let's say I need to implement a single endpoint that:

- accepts a path parameter and several query string parameters
- validates the params
- constructs a db query based on the params
- executes the query
- sends response back to client

From my research I understand this is a good use case for akka http and modeling the flow of the request -> response seems to map well to using akka streams with several `Flow`s but I'd like some clarification:

1. Does using the akka streams library make sense here?
2. Is that still true if the database driver making the call does not have an async api?
3. Do the stream back pressure semantics still hold true if there is a Flow making a blocking call?
4. How is parallelism handled with the akka streams implementation? Say for example the service experiences 500 concurrent connections, does the streams abstraction simply have a pool of actors under the covers to handle each of these connections?

Edit: This answers most of the questions I had: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/handling-blocking-operations-in-akka-http-routes.html

Comment: See here for "high level server api": http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/http/routing-dsl/index.html  lots of good examples

Comment: A simple Request => Response action is more suited to something like Play or http4s. Akka streams are suited for well, "streams". As in, websockets, large quantities of data, or fast streaming of data.

Comment: I second http4s, I use it as a service layer.  On top of my akka streaming framework.  Akka persists to dB, and http4s and doobie serve the content via rest

Comment: The link provided by Ramon is dead, here's new link: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.16/scala/routing.html